# How reduce not used capacity of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

After some convert `ArrayList` have 3 elements, `ArrayList` size is biggest then 3. So `NullPointerException` occurs when uses `forEach` circle.

How does avoid this situation? I mean without `!=null` checks.

Example:

```
List<String> busesIdToRemove = driverWrapper.getBusesIdToRemove();
```

List contains id's those entities, which will be remove. Error occurs in place:

```
for (String id : busesIdToRemove) { 
Long longId = Long.valueOf(id); //here. Because id is null ... 
}
```

But, actually, list contains only elements with not empty values.

For example [index, value].

1, "41";

4, "50" ...

Info about elements with indexes [0],[2],[3] is absent in debugger, and return null for `get(0)` e.g. method.

Problem resolved with: arrayList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

Comment: Please post an example illustrating your problem.

Comment: If the size is bigger than 3, then the list has more than 3 elements, by definition. And if some are null, then you added/set them as null. Just don't.

Comment: Example: List<String> busesIdToRemove = driverWrapper.getBusesIdToRemove(); 

List contains id's those entities, which will be remove. 
Error occurs in place: 
for (String id : busesIdToRemove) { 
Long longId = Long.valueOf(id); //here. Because id is null ... 
}
But, actually, list contains only elements with not empty values.
For example [index, value]. 1, "41"; 4, "50" info about elements with indexes [0],[2],[3] is absent in debugger, and return null for get(0) e.g. method. 

Problem resolved with: arrayList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single line technique to remove all `null` item from your `arrayList`

```
arrayList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

And to be sure about size just see the value of `arrayList.size()`

Answer (score 5):

If size is bigger than 3 it means you didnt properly remove the elements. Setting them to null is not removing.

You need to use arrayList.remove(item) method.